# Significant Figures: To expand or not to expand?

Tags: terminology

4 * (2 + 2) = ?

4 * 4 = 20  (rounded to 1 significant figure)
OR
4 * 2 + 4 * 2 = 16

2.0 * (0.5 + 0.5) = ?

2.0 * 1.0 = 2.0
OR
2.0 * 0.5 + 2.0 * 0.5 = 2

Comment: When I multiply 4 by 4, I get 16, not 20.

Comment: 4 has one significant figure.  When you multiply two numbers with one significant figure, you are supposed to get a new number with one significant figure.  16 rounds to 20.

Comment: What the heck this has to do with chemistry ?!

Comment: There wasn't a laboratory science category so since most of the other significant figures questions are placed in the chemistry category, I decided to put my significant figures question in the chemistry category too.

Comment: Significant figures are **math** lessons used in chemistry, not chemistry. This Q should get removed. Your explanation puts this in chemistry category; and I'm not meaning to be insulting or something, but with this explanation we should merge math into chemistry!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about significant figures outside of a chemistry context.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, the 4(2+2), if you were ABSOLUTELY going to adhere to significant figure rules, then 20 would be the correct answer, though I don't believe many people would fault you for saying 16. In your second case, 2.0(0.5+0.5), the appropriate answer here would indeed be 2.0.

In any case, significant figures are not really valuable when referring to purely mathematical equations like you did. We use them in order to avoid making errors when it comes to the accuracy of a result, in other words, significant figures are there so that your answer is not more specific than your measurement was. In mathematics, this is not an issue, as you are not making any measurements. So, while you COULD use significant figures in a situation like this, it really is not quite the appropriate situation in which to do so.